# Javascript get all Properties of Object

Tags: javascript

I have an Javascript Object and I want to give out all Properties of this Object.

Currently I´m having this Piece of Code, which gives me the Name of all Properties.
But if it´s a Function I also need all Parameters the Function would accept.

```
for(var property in Object) {
    console.log(property);
}

Output
...
...
...
TD
explicitJoin
hashCode
getED
queryConditions
getDisplayTagName
getClass
displayValue
addCondition
getEncodedString
getDisplayValue
addOrCondition
multiple
...
...
...
```

Comment: You're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties

Comment: Strange mess of OOP terms...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "interface"? Please explain exactly what you want. Do you want the list of formal parameters the function accepts?

Comment: In OOP, an Interface is usually a class-like construct that specifies methods and attributes that an object that implements it must have. It is used as a half-way step to multiple inheritance that avoids the problems caused by multiple inheritance. **JavaScript has nothing like it** so it makes no sense to ask what interface an object has.

Comment: By interface I mean the parameters the function accepts! Updated the Question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using

```
 for(var property in Object) {
    console.log(property);
}
```

you will get key of each element, If that property is a function and you want to use values than use

```
Object[property]
```

Comment: if it is working for you than you can accept the answer, thanks.

Comment: I must wait 2 minutes till I can accept the answer ;)